# Java Null pointer exception on creating an intent?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am not sure why I keep getting a null pointer error:

This is the error:

```
11-06 13:50:03.539  27297-27297/com.example.lior.winklio E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example, PID: 27297
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
            at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3813)
            at com.example.StarterFragment.sendToHomePage(StarterFragment.java:227)
            at com.example.StarterFragment.access$1700(StarterFragment.java:37)
            at com.example.StarterFragment$2.success(StarterFragment.java:184)
            at com.example.StarterFragment$2.success(StarterFragment.java:176)
            at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(CallbackRunnable.java:45)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is the code: (the error points to the Intent homeInter ...)

```
private void sendToHomePage() {

        Log.i(TAG, " SENDING TO HOME PAGE...");

        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);

        // Closing all the Activities
        homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring add item
        startActivity(homeIntent);
        getActivity().finish();
    }
```

Comment: Your getActivity() might be null. Have you debugged your code ?

Comment: If you are calling from within an activity you should use `this` as the context, otherwise use getContext().

Comment: Indeed, as StackFlowed pointed out, the problem is exactly that getActivity() is returning null.

Comment: I am calling it from a fragment...getContext(), that is not a possible it is not a command I can use...I have to call getActivity().getApplicationContext()... unless I am missing something here... And just to clarify I am not always getting this errors, it works fine sometimes, i get the error here and there.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext, MainActivity.class);
```